# Dynamic variable name in loop

Tags: javascript

I need to create dynamic variable name in js inside for loop

```
var counter = 0;
for(i=0; i<location.length; i++) {
   ...
   var "marker_" + counter = new google.maps.Marker({
```

But when i expected to have variables marker_0,marker_1,marker_2,... i had this error

```
Error: SyntaxError: missing variable name
Source Code:
          var "marker_" + counter = new google.maps.Marker({
```

Comment: You'll want to use eval() to make things work that way.  However, go with the array solution, IMO.

Comment: I don't see a point of making a dynamic variable in a loop like that since the context will only be in the scope of the current iteration. If you're looking to reuse outside the loop you're going to need to use an array.

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP. I don't even see how this has to deal with jQuery, but I'll let the JS pros handle that.

Comment: I removed the [jQuery] tag - this has nowt to do with jQuery.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use an array:

```
var marker = [];

for (i=0; i < location.length; i++) {
   marker[counter] = new google.maps.Marker({
```

Answer (score 4):

Well, "Use an array" is undoubtably the right answer here, however if you *really* want dynamic variables you need to decide the scope of them - the default would be `window` and then you could do this:

```
var counter = 0;
for(i=0; i<location.length; i++) {
   ...
   window["marker_" + counter] = new google.maps.Marker({
```

This can now be accessed with the same square bracket notation

```
window["marker_0"]...
```

or the dot notation

```
window.marker_0
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is used as a duplicate target:

[Use an array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14442923/157247) is good advice if the information you want to access is keyed numerically. If it isn't, you have two options:

1. Use an object and dynamic property access
2. Use a `Map` (ES2015+)

#### Using an object

You can access object properties using a string (or, in ES2015+, a Symbol) via brackets notation, so you can store information in an object to access later using strings/Symbols:

```js
var theData = Object.assign(Object.create(null), {
    x: "ecks",
    y: "why"
});

var key = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "x" : "y";
console.log("key = " + key + ", theData[key] = " + theData[key]);
```

#### Using a Map

You can use a Map instead of an object even with strings or Symbols as keys, but unlike objects, Map keys can be any JavaScript value (except negative 0, but hey, good enough):

```js
const theData = new Map([
    ["x", "ecks"],
    ["y", "why"]
]);

const key = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "x" : "y";
console.log("key = " + key + ", theData.get(key) = " + theData.get(key));
```

That example uses strings, but again, Map keys can be any type. A Map key can even be an object.