# Javascript: Multiple arrays initialization

Tags: javascript, arrays

Want to initialize array in Javascript with a name pattern like this:

```
var lineData0= [];
var lineData1= [];
var lineData2= [];
....
```

try to initialize the array like this:

```
for(var i=0; i<60; i++){
  var lineData+"i"= [];
}
```

Doesn't work?
Is there any easy way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic variable name in loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442896/dynamic-variable-name-in-loop)

Comment: Whenever you have something like `varnameX` where `X` is a running number, you want an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use an array of arrays instead:

```
var lineData = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    lineData.push([]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, every object it's like a dictionary. You can do it this way:

```
var dictionary = {};

for(var i=0; i<60; i++){
  dictionary["lineData"+i]= [];
}

//set data
dictionary["lineData0"].push('hello');
dictionary["lineData1"].push('world');

//Print stuff
console.log(dictionary["lineData0"][0]);
console.log(dictionary["lineData1"][0]);
```