# Looping names of instances of an object

Tags: javascript, oop, instance

I need a for loop to generate 4 different instances of an object, all with different names.

```
for(z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
        obstacleY = 699 + (z * 100);
        console.log(obstacleY);
        mg_terrain = new mg_terrain(1000, obstacleY, 120, 30);
}
```

I want to write something like mg_terrain + z = new mg_terrain(...); but I don't know the correct way of doing this.

Comment: One obvious problem is you're shadowing the constructor with the instance name. But if you want four instance, why not just use an array?

Answer (score 1):

There has to be a dupetarget for this, but basically, you use an *array*:

```
var terrains = [];                                          // ***
for(z = 0; z < 4; z++) {
    obstacleY = 699 + (z * 100);
    console.log(obstacleY);
    terrains[z] = new mg_terrain(1000, obstacleY, 120, 30);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^
}
```

An array lets you maintain an ordered collection of things -- in this case, `mg_terrain` objects -- and access them by index (0, 1, etc.).

If at some point you want to know how long the array is, you'd use its `length` property (`terrains.length`). The highest index for an array is one less than its `length` (e.g., if `length` is 4, there are four items: indexes 0, 1, 2, an 3).

Comment: Found the dupetarget: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442896/dynamic-variable-name-in-loop