# how to get a value in array of variables by using a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

filteredArray is an array of variables So, I want to get a variable from it by searching in to it using a string and I want directly to use this variable in another code, can you help me?

```
     
      const filteredArray = [livingRrooms, kitchens, ceilingsDesigns, bedroomsArray ];
    // z is the string I get from a code that i have
         const z = "livingRrooms kitchens ceilingsDesigns bedroomsArray";
           function checkvar(cas) {
               return z.includes(cas);
                                 }
      // as you can see next line is working just find     
           console.log(checkvar("kitchens"));
     // this dosn't work because find use a srtict mode I need a way around it or anonther way
           console.log(filteredArray.find(checkvar));
```

Comment: *"filteredArray is an array of variables"* No, it's an array of *values*. Those values came from some variables, but there is no link from the array back to the variables where the values came from.

Comment: If you need not to use repeating values to the `filteredArray` then you can change the data structure from `Array` to `Object`. Do it like `const data = {livingRooms, kitchens, ceilingsDesigns, bedroomsArray, ...}`

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442896/dynamic-variable-name-in-loop, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695050/add-a-property-to-a-javascript-object-using-a-variable-as-the-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> filteredArray is an array of variables

No, it's an array of *values*. Those values came from some variables, but there is no link from the array back to the variables where the values came from. If (for instance) both `livingRooms` and `kitchens` have the value 5, you have **no way** of knowing (at runtime) where either of the `5`s in the array came from.

If you want to look for variables by name, use the variables to create object properties:

```
const items = {livingRooms, kitches, ceilingsDesigns/*...*/};
```

Then if you have `x` with the value `"livingRooms"`, you can use `items[x]` to get the value for the `livingRooms` property from `items`.

Comment: thanks a lot, my code got simpler now by changing the array into an object.

Comment: but how can I make a link between the value of the variable and the object that has the the variable, because when I fetch the variable from the object I don't get the initial value of it instead I get an  object and when I console the length of the fetched variable it get me the length of the string of the variable instead of the Array length that the variable has as a value.

Comment: @ammarmohamed - I'm afraid I don't quite understand what you mean by that. Perhaps post a new question showing the problem and explaining what result you're trying to get?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68428457/how-to-match-a-custom-data-value-with-an-object-containing-variables-in-js this is where i posted the question. may you help me?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what Sajeeb proposed

```js
const inventory = [
  {name: 'apples', quantity: 2},
  {name: 'bananas', quantity: 0},
  {name: 'cherries', quantity: 5}
];

function isCherries(fruit) {
  return fruit.name === 'cherries';
}

console.log(inventory.find(isCherries));
// { name: 'cherries', quantity: 5 }
```