# why do i get value not defined when using an eval() statment

Tags: javascript, class, eval

```
var count = 0
class node{
            data;
            leftchild;
            rightchild;
            constructor(data){
                this.data = data;
            }
            addleftchild(value){
                this.leftchild = value
            }
            addrightchild(value){
                this.rightchild = value
            }
            ///getter
            get data(){
                return this.data;
            }
```

this is the class im using

```
function addnode(num){
            eval("let value = nod"+num+".data")
            console.log(value)
```

when i call this function all i get as an output is
tree.html:42 Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined
at addnode
the problem seems to be when i try to log value it is undefined

Comment: Question is - why you need to eval it? Why not have array of elements and than do `let value = globalObject[num].data`

Comment: Because `let` is block-scoped, so it only exists within the scope of the `eval` call. You could declare it in the containing scope (`let value; eval("value = ...");`) but what you have above is an anti-pattern (not least because it doesn't do anything to ensure `num` isn't malicious code). See [this question's answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14442896/dynamic-variable-name-in-loop) for what to do instead (TL;DR - use an array).

Comment: If you have a method that takes a number and does something with a node, the node being associated with that number, why aren't you using an *array* which associates an index with some data? Or a map that associates anything that is used as a key with a piece of data? Why does this *have to* be `eval()`-ed dynamically generated variable name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eval code is executed as if it were in a block ([reference](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/global-object.html#sec-performeval)), so this

```
eval("let value = nod"+num+".data")
console.log(value)
```

is roughly the same as

```
{
   let value = nod5.data
}
console.log(value) // error because 'value' didn't survive the block
```

You can work around this by assigning to an already existing variable:

```
let value
eval("value = nod" + num + ".data")
```

or by moving the assignment outside `eval`

```
let value = eval("nod" + num + ".data")
```

The question remains open, of course, whether you need `eval` here in the first place. I guess you rather need an array here, so that instead of a dynamic variable `nod5` you could simply use `nodes[5]`.

Comment: thank you i think i should have implemented an array instead like you said in hindsight but thank you